# Disable the international keyboard selection button from the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

Is it possible to disable the international keyboard selection button from the default keyboard through out the app ?
If yes means, please give some idea to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to hide the keyboard in iOS 6. Instead restrict the languages in the language list

Open on simulator Settings application ->General->International->Language. Select here your language and keyboard will have required letters.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Its a main system feature. When you have enabled multiple keyboard layouts in your settings this button appears automatically.